# Red5 on Debian, output PID

Tags: linux, bash, debian, pid, red5

I'm fumbling my way through with this one, as a novice with all things linux so please be patient :)

I would like to output the process ID of a program to a file. From my readings this is generally achieved by a special pling variable which linux maintains:

```
make_something_run.sh &
echo $! > /var/run/someting.pid
```

however when I try to apply this in my startup script for red5, it creates the pid file successfully but no id is found within. This is the specific script:

```
start)
    echo -n "Starting Red5"
    echo -n " "
    cd $RED5_HOME
    su -s /bin/bash -c "$RED5_HOME/$RED5_PROG.sh &" $RED5_USER
    echo "$RED5_HOME/$RED5_PROG.sh &"
## su -s /bin/bash -c "$RED5_HOME/$RED5_PROG.sh > start.log &" $RED5_USER
    echo $! > /var/run/red5.pid
    wait $!
    sleep 2
   ;;
```

I've tried with and without the `wait $!` (which I believe waits for the process to start before writing the file?) with no success. My only other thoughts are to do something fancy with grep and ps aux to extract the number, though I've no idea if that would be a reliable approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an echo
`make_something_run.sh & echo $! > /var/run/someting.pid`
                                                     **^**
http://www.odi.ch/weblog/posting.php?posting=291
EDIT:
`su -s /bin/bash -c "${RED5_HOME}/${RED5_PROG}.sh & echo \$! > /var/run/red5.pid" $RED5_USER`
or
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197165/getting-a-pid-from-a-background-process-run-as-another-user

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have edited the post to include the omitted echo in my example, it is however present lower down in my post in the script I'm having problems with, so not the fix to my problem

Comment: Can you try with `su -s /bin/bash -c "${RED5_HOME}/${RED5_PROG}.sh &" $RED5_USER` I have seen you echo test, but it is normal to use {} when you have to put variable together with text

Comment: You must have me sorry but I'm a little rusty on sh and bash. But I can also see that there might be a problem, you are using `bash` in `su`. Try also with `su -s /bin/bash -c "${RED5_HOME}/${RED5_PROG}.sh & echo $! > /var/run/red5.pid" $RED5_USER`

Comment: Yes, that is you problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197165/getting-a-pid-from-a-background-process-run-as-another-user I just see that this question have to be ask in stackoverflow.com

Comment: That looks complicated! Thanks for your efforts, I'll see how I get on

Comment: @DibloDk: Your last command is almost right, change is to `su -s /bin/bash -c '${RED5_HOME}/${RED5_PROG}.sh & echo $! > /var/run/red5.pid' $RED5_USER`. Notice the single quotes, otherwise the `$!` gets already expanded prior to the command execution and hence leads to a wrong PID.

Comment: was just about to post similar, in the end I got it to work by escaping the $! var: `su -s /bin/bash -c "${RED5_HOME}/${RED5_PROG}.sh > start.log & echo \$! > /var/run/red5.pid" $RED5_USER`

Comment: Oh yes, sry :-)

Comment: @milks: I just wanted to correct my comment: You are absolutely right. You _have to to it via escaping_, otherwise `${RED5_USER}` won't be expanded... (I used a too trivial command to test `;)`)

Comment: @DibloDk: Please consider to expand your answer, so that the solution for `su ...` (i.e. the original question) is directly in it. Then, some later visitor won't need to dig through the comments `:)`